# Push image from client side to users in ViewController from parse framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I am creating a demo application that uses `parse framework`. i want to show images in my UIImageView  from my developer parse  account to all users installed my app. How can i achieve this? 
Waiting for your help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can store images on parse:

1) Create an object with field imageURL (for example) and store link to an image. In this case you will need to load image by this URL in your app (you can use AFNetworking UIImageView category to do it in background).

In this case you will need additional api to store images on server (or S3)

2) You can save image data at Parse. There is good documentation you can use to build it this way [Store Images at Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files-images/iOS)